# Unsolved Twitter Widget Mystery of the Ages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, twitter

Here's one that has perplexed designers for years now, even over the course of Twitter changes and countless hours of hair-pulling and blame-the-developer.

Twitter produces its own js widget for rendering a timeline. Here's a sample of the code without any customization, for an actual account - pasted as found in the interest of science rather than readability:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/OT_Tweep/lists/ordinary-twitter" data-widget-id="570958838329643008">Tweets from https://twitter.com/OT_Tweep/lists/ordinary-twitter</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I'm too noob here to include images directly. Here's a link to how it's supposed to look - and does in fact look on many browsers/machines - like Safari and, today but not yesterday!, Chrome - also on Firefox for mobile:

http://ordinary-gentlemen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/correct_twitter_widget_display_safari.png

Here's how it renders on Firefox 36.0/Windows 7:

http://ordinary-gentlemen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/twitter_widget_display_firefox.png

Not cool! But not a pure Firefox issue, nor a WordPress issue, and not a new issue. Literally as of a couple of days ago, the display on Chrome was, to use the technical term, kerflooey (embarrassingly worse than either of the above examples), as it had been for months. I don't recall having changed any setting on Chrome in the meantime, though I have used it a bit more than usual while investigating a different mystery (why an image appeared on my Chrome, but not someone else's, though on his iPad, but not his desktop, etc.).

There's a Twitter Developer Forum thread going back to 2012, continued for a at least a couple of years, never fully resolved, featuring one complaint after another. Some users seem to think they've solved the problem, others remain joyless. I'd link it, but I'm also over the newbie limit for links in a post. If anyone is interested, I'd be happy to post it in a thread.

I'm not sure I should hope that this question will put me over the 10 reputation hurdle, but I'd be very interested to learn if someone has a solution or explanation.

ADDENDUM: I should also note that a version of the widget displays fine on one WordPress site I'm using, but not another, through same browser/machine. Nor does disabling all Firefox add-ons and extensions produce desired rendering on the problem site. The thread I cannot post mentions the problems on Drupal and other sites, and a wide range of fixes, none of which fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want total control over the Twitter feed, you'd be better off to develop your own using the Twitter API and PHP.

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

The default js twitter widget is unreliable and obviously doesn't work on all browsers or devices.

What you need is the php twitter api to generate exactly the html that you want so you can have more control over the styling.

Let me know if you need help! I've developed a twitter module for Drupal.

Comment: Lots of work's been done over the years on this general topic of Twitter add-ons, and I may look into a custom widget over time. I remain curious about the possible explanations for this behavior, and possible fixes for it. Here's the Developer Forum thread I mentioned, but couldn't link in the OP: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-widget-not-working-on-my-website/18054

Comment: It does sound like some kind of issue with the js that twitter has provided. I've seen issues where the profile images for everyone using the API or a js widget will disappear.

If you'd like to use my module for twitter feeds, let me know. I can package it up for you.

Comment: Thanks for the kind offer, I think I can follow the Github presentation, unless there's some new trick to it worth knowing, when I am able next to work on that site (where I'm just volunteering, and do not yet have adequate access to add functions safely).